# adding placeholder text to select input - firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am having trouble getting placeholder text for a select dropdown input to display in firefox. It works fine in IE and Chrome.

My CSS:

```
select option:first-child {color: #666666;display: none;}
```

My HTML:

```
<select name="exp_date" id="exp_date" style="width: 50%; display: inline; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; border-right: none; cursor: pointer;" class="form-control" title="Enter Expiration Date - Month">
    <option selected="" value="" label="Month">
    </option><option value="01" label="1">1
    </option><option value="02" label="2">2
    </option><option value="03" label="3">3
    ...
</select>
```

**how it looks in chrome**
[image]

**how it looks in firefox**
[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Could you please share the code , it would be helpful to understand the problem

Comment: edited to add code. sorry about that

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5p2ufwue/2/) Open this on mozilla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add option with month value in below format it will act as placeholder and it will worki in chrome as well as firefox.

```
<select name="exp_date" id="exp_date" style="width: 50%; display: inline; border-top-left-radius: 0px; border-bottom-left-radius: 0px; border-right: none; cursor: pointer;" class="form-control" title="Enter Expiration Date - Month">
        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Month</option>
        </option><option value="01" label="1">1
        </option><option value="02" label="2">2
        </option><option value="03" label="3">3
        ...
    </select>
```

Comment: thanks deja and mahip_j. both your responses worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I believe placeholder on select is not support on Mozilla. Rather you can add an option with empty value with selected attribute. For example,

```
<option selected="selected" disabled hidden>Month</option>
```

Comment: thanks deja and mahip_j. both your responses worked perfectly